# Not being able to start a java-program with more RAM

Tags: java, variables, memory

I just wanted to start a java program with the following extra parameters:

> -Xmx3G -Xms1G

However I get the following message:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Incompatible minimum and
>   maximum heap sizes specified Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

I searched for what it could mean and it had to do with the environment variable _JAVA_OPTIONS However I do not have this variable set,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRqHT.png

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the variable and restart your pc and delete it again (restart afterwards) and than it worked again.